# Oauth2 on Google Contacts API For DotNet - Token Invalid – AuthSub token has wrong scope

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

I have created a class that authorises a vb.net app to access Google Fusion Tables using  Oauth2. It opens a web browser in a form if needed, encrypts and stores the refresh token, and it works well. I can access the fusion tables data.

However, I would also like to access Contacts. I have requested access to Contacts from the user.

I can retrieve the AccessToken that works for fusion tables and have tried different techniques to get things working on contacts, but no luck. I keep getting a 401-unauthorised error. But I **can** get Contacts working if I use clientlogin.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My latest try:

```
Dim rs As New RequestSettings("App Name", p.AccessToken) 'String retrieved from class
Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(rs)
Dim q As New FeedQuery
q.Uri = New Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<EMAIL>/full/<IDCODE>")
Dim c As New Contact
c = cr.Retrieve(Of Contact)(q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Claudio Cherubino for the suggestion. I was actually already using that scope. Thankfully, I have now, finally, found the answer.

I was literally missing a single letter:

```
q.Uri = New Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<EMAIL>/full/<IDCODE>")
```

... is wrong, as the scope I requested was indeed:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
```

So the Uri needed to match, with httpS. I added the 's' and it works. Correct code below:

```
q.Uri = New Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/<EMAIL>/full/<IDCODE>")
```

Many thanks for this post for the answer:
http://www.geoffmcqueen.com/2010/03/14/token-invalid-authsub-token-has-wrong-scope-oauth-google-problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to request access to the Contacts API OAuth scope, which is `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`.

The .NET client library includes an OAuth 2.0 sample that uses the Contacts API:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs